# Rails Controller Check if Turbolinks Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am developing a Ruby on Rails 4 application that is using the Turbolinks gem. I have noticed when a link is clicked the layout is still rendered server side but the Turbolinks JavaScript just grabs the body out of this rendered content. My question is on the controller side is it possible to determine if a request is made via Turbolinks or not. Essentially in the event a request is made via Turbolinks I want to set the layout to false as to not execute un-needed code. In my ApplicationController I already have the following code:

```
# Don't use layout when AJAX request
layout proc { |controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false: "application" }
```

This code prevents an AJAX request from rendering the header if I make an AJAX request via jQuery, however it doesn't seem to do anything when it comes to Turbolinks.

Comment: Would rendering without a layout not break the Turbolinks process? Turbolinks will (quote): `keep the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head`. So it looks like Turbolinks relies on the full page layout to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

For Turbo (the descendant of Turbolinks), the only solution that I found  is to check `formats.any?(:turbo_stream)`. This is because Turbo inserts a "turbo-stream" accepts header.

Unless you're using Frames, then there will also be a "Turbo-Frame" header.

It also inserts a CSRF token, but I don't think that is any guarantee that the request is from Turbo.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit of a hack, I found that checking the header for "X-XHR-Referer" seems to do the trick.

```
unless request.headers["X-XHR-Referer"].present? 
    do_some_stuff
end
```

It seems that Turbolinks add the header for some redirection handling. This may change in the future though.

Comment: A while back I implemented my own bastardized version of Turbolinks to achieve this, but found that sometimes when using the back button in the browser a page would render without the body and things would look terrible. I quickly decided it wasn't worth the effort and I should just use either PJAX or standard AJAX for my needs. But thanks for the share.